# Using tagged unions from JavaScript with wasm-bindgen

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

I have a JavaScript object type where the `kind` field determines what other fields are present. Examples:

```js
{ kind: 0, name: "foo" }
{ kind: 1, name: "foo", value: 69 }
{ kind: 2 }
```

I put it into an `extern` block to use it in Rust:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
extern "C" {
    type Foo;
}
```

I need to access a `Foo` value's fields in this function:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
fn use_foo(foo: Foo) {
    // ...
}
```

How do I do this in a type-safe way?